# Removing Characters from SAS String Starting on Left

Tags: sas, substring

I have a SAS string that always starts with a date. I want to remove the date from the substring.

Example of data is below (data does not have bullets, included bullets to increase readability)

- 10/01/2016|test_num15
- 11/15/2016|recom_1_test1
- 03/04/2017|test_0_8_i0|vacc_previous0

I want the data to look like this (data does not have bullets, included bullets to increase readability)

- test_num15
- recom_1_test1
- test_0_8_i0|vacc_previous0

Comment: Is the date always in that format and always exactly 10 characters? Just use `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

Index find '|' position in the string, then substr substring; or use regular expression.

```
data have;
input x $50.;
x1=substr(x,index(x,'|')+1);
x2=prxchange('s/([^_]+\|)(?=\w+)//',1,x);
cards;
10/01/2016|test_num15
11/15/2016|recom_1_test1
03/04/2017|test_0_8_i0|vacc_previous0
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for `call scan`.  If your length of date is constant (always 10), then you don't actually need this (`start` would be 12 then and skip to the `substr`, as user667489 noted in comments), but if it's not this would be helpful.

```
data have;
length textstr $100;
input textstr $;
datalines;
10/01/2016|test_num15
11/15/2016|recom_1_test1
03/04/2017|test_0_8_i0|vacc_previous0
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  call scan(textstr,2,start,length,'|');
  new_textstr = substr(textstr,start);
run;
```

It would also let you grab the second word only if that's useful (using `length` third argument for substr).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Joe (great name too - both my son and father and both father-in-laws are named Joe as well)!